# Replace values in one column for specific instances of another column

Tags: python, string, pandas, str-replace

I am new to Pandas and not sure how to do the following:

I have a dataframe (df) with several columns. One column is called

```
OldCat = ['a-nn', 'bb-nm', 'ab-pp', 'ba-nn', 'cc-nm', 'ca-mn']
```

Now I want to create a new column that organizes/categories OldCat in a new way (NewCat). Specifically, I would like to look for strings in OldCat that contain either a(at the beginning), ba or ca
j='^a|ba|ca' 
and then replace nan in NewCat with 'A' in the rows where OldCat contains j. 
In R this would be something like this:

```
 j='^a|ba|ca'
 df[(OldCat %like% j),NewCat := str_replace_all(df[(OldCat %like% j),NewCat], "nan", "A")]
```

Since R is relatively slow with my very large dataset, I decided to switch to pandas but I am not sure how to get the same result.
Cheers

Comment: Sorry for matches you want to replace with 'nan' and for others 'A'?

Comment: So NewCat is a column that at the moment only contains nan. Now I want to replace nan in NewCat only where OldCat contains j

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the vectorised `str.extract` to return matches with `fillna` to replace `NaN` with the string `'nan'`:

```
In [119]:
df['NewCat'] = df['OldCat'].str.extract('(^a|ba|ca)', expand=False).fillna('nan')
df

Out[119]:
  OldCat NewCat
0      a      a
1     bb    nan
2     ab      a
3     ba     ba
4     cc    nan
5     ca     ca
```

**EDIT**

IIUC then you can use `str.contains` with `loc` to set just the rows that contain the strings:

```
In [137]:
df.loc[df['OldCat'].str.contains(r'a|ba|ca'), 'NewCat'] = 'A'
df['NewCat'].fillna('nan', inplace=True)
df

Out[137]:
  OldCat NewCat
0   a-nn      A
1  bb-nm    nan
2  ab-pp      A
3  ba-nn      A
4  cc-nm    nan
5  ca-mn      A
```

Comment: Can you edit your question with the desired output, also check my updated answer